# "(453) A session key is required for calling this method" during facebook post delete

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I am using c# facebook sdk. I am trying to delete a facebook post from my application(post was created from my application). I am getting a "*(453) A session key is required for calling this method*" error message.

**I have granted offline_access,publish_stream responsibilities to my application.**

```
string url = string.Concat( "https://graph.facebook.com/", postId );        
Facebook.FacebookClient queryClient = new FacebookClient( AppID, AppSecret );
url += "?method=delete&access_token=" + AppAccessToken;
IDictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>( );
parameters[ "access_token" ] = AppAccessToken;
object result = queryClient.Post( url, parameters );
```

I also tried queryClient.Delete but kept getting a (400) invalid webrequest error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For version 5.x, The valid syntax for deletion is (you don't need the querystring parameters)

to delete a comment, post, or photo that was created with the API:

`object result = queryClient.Delete('ObjectId');`

to remove a like

`object result = queryClient.Delete('ObjectId/likes');`

See: http://docs.csharpsdk.org/docs/making-synchronous-requests.html

**Edit - 400 Bad Request**

Try running a .Get(postid) first then run the .Delete().

Comment: Tried using queryClient.Delete(postid). I am getting a "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request." error msg.

Comment: Try running a .Get(postid) first then run the .Delete().

Comment: It's a known bug in the C# SDK.  I don't know if they've ported all the known bugs from the old site to githug yet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make that call with a user access token for a user currently logged in to your app (hence 'session' in the error message)

Comment: But i have already granted offline_access permission to my app.Moreover the graph api documentation only asks for publish_stream permissions

Comment: You're using an app access token there, you're supposed to use a user access token for that call